# Bash: how to properly accept user input?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, command-line, input

I couldn't find an example online but I'm sure I've seen shell coders use `${1:--}` to accept user input. Here's an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

var="${1:--}"
echo "$var"
```

Then, run it:

```
$ ./test.sh "this is a test"
```

My question is: how is using `"${1:--}"` to accept user input different from `"$1"`?

Comment: What do you mean by "user input"? Supplied on the command line, or read from the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${1:--}` will expand to the string "-" if there is no parameter one or if the parameter is empty.

So `./test.sh ""` will return the string "-" as will the command `./test.sh` This is considered to be a useful default in many circumstances where an argument of "-" can mean `stdin` or `stdout`.  Also it makes sure scripts don't break when a parameter is not explicitly set.

Answer (score 0):

Under bash's parameter expansion you can use default value of the variable and this is what `${1:--}` does to thirst command argument, namely it assigns value `-` if and only if `$1` is unset or null. It works with any other parameters too, test this example:

```
echo "${var:-X}"   # var is not defined so X will be echoed
var=Y              # lets define var
echo "${var:-X}"   # var is defined so its value Y will be printed
```